# Jboss proxy bypass for localhost

Tags: jboss, proxy

I have an instance of JBoss running on machine 1 and all calls get routed through a proxy.
It all works fine.

I have a condition where 1 war needs to call the other war on the same machine.

The calls get routed through the proxy and fails.

Is there a way to by-pass the proxy for localhost?

When I don't have the proxy setup it works fine, but fails on other calls using the proxy.

I need to know if there is a way to turn off proxy for localhost or calls within the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|10.*.*.*"` to list the hosts that should not go through a proxy.

Comment: I am having the same issue as OP and I tried your approach but it seems like the option is not recognized. I don't know if it has to do with the java options being within quotes and for the none proxy host I also use quotes.